# debugging JSP in eclipse running on SAP Hybris Server

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, jsp-tags, sap-commerce-cloud

I not able to enter into the debug mode in eclipse, I'm building an application using SAP Hybris.
Here we are using builtin Hybris server.

Answer (score 1):

Was the Hybris server started in the Debug mode ? If yes, make sure that the port used by the server for debugging is the same with the one you are trying to connect to !

The port which is used by Hybris should be logged at the server startup, e.g:

***Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000***

Answer (score 1):

add this line `tomcat.debugjavaoptions=-Xverify:none -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n` to your **local.properites** and then execute `ant all` to update tomcat configuration and after that if you  run platform using `hybrisserver.bat debug` it will start in debug mode. Make sure your eclipse remote debugger is trying to connect on 8000 port

Answer (score 1):

Also, you will have to let the JSP compile first (first request). so, you will have to reload the page again for the debugger to stop for you.

Thirdly, the debugger may not stop at any random piece of JSP code. You will likely have to add a scriptlet (simple sysout) and add the debug point there to be able to engage the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Hope, you are looking for ***[how to debug hybris application?](https://www.helphybris.com/2018/03/how-to-debug-hybris-application.html)***

> As Hybris runs in builin server, you can debug it as Remote
>   Java Application from Eclipse

- start the server with `hybrisserver.bat debug` (In windows) or `./hybrisserver.sh debug` (In linux)
- Import all required `extensions` in eclipse
- Open any Java file (`cartPageController.java`)
- Open `Run > Debug Configurations` (shortcut: `Alt + r + b`)
- check for `Remote Java Application` in your left pannel of popup
- Right click on `Remote Java Applicaiton` and click on new
- Create new configuration by clicking on `Apply`
- Click on `Debug` to start your `debug mode`

Nowe enjoys the debugging by putting breakpoints.

Comment: I know this procedure, But I'm not able to debug JSP.It will not stop at breakpoints

Comment: JSPs is all about presentation, which should rarely (if ever) require debugging through IDE. Refer [this](https://waynebeaton.wordpress.com/2006/07/11/debugging-jsps-using-eclipse-webtools/), [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/workshop102/webapplications/workshopJSP/tutorialJSP/TutorialJSPDebug.html) posts if it could help you